# BlackBerry maps location document with multiple points

Tags: blackberry, maps, latitude-longitude

When I implement BlackBerry maps in my application using the code from RIM in [How To - Invoke BlackBerry Maps](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/How_To_-_Invoke_BlackBerry_Maps.html?nodeid=1366963&vernum=0#4), my map works fine with Ontario points, but when I use 
Latitude 13.083333 and Longitude: 80.283333, it does not work.

What about the dot? On skipping the dot, it shows the incorrect position.

```
String document = "<lbs>
<location lon='-8030000' lat='4326000' label='Kitchener, ON' description='Kitchener, Ontario, Canada' />
<location lon='-7569792' lat='4542349' label='Ottawa, ON' description='Ottawa, Ontario, Canada' />
```

";

Comment: I don't know what this means: "What about the dot? On skipping the dot, it shows the incorrect position."

Comment: did u check the link "How To - Invoke Blackberry Maps"? there given some examples.. and in my code also lon="-8030000" actuall longitude shown in google maps is -80.30000. what about the decimal point???

Answer (score 1):

The right way would be to multiply LAT & LONG by 100,000 and cast it to an integer value,
something like this:

```
    // LAT & LONG times 100,000, converted to integer
    int lon = (int) (80.283333 * 100000);
    int lat = (int) (13.083333 * 100000);

    String label = "Label of point on map";
    String desc = "Description of point when clicked";

    // create the location element
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<location");
    sb.append(" lon='").append(String.valueOf(lon)).append("'");
    sb.append(" lat='").append(String.valueOf(lat)).append("'");
    sb.append(" label='").append(label).append("'");
    sb.append(" description='").append(desc).append("'");
    sb.append(" />");
```